# How to validate list of names for a Server

Tags: python, pandas, bash, shell

I am pulling the NTP records from thousand os servers via a script, and the list looks like below.

### File which contains Server Name and NTP Servers:

```
dbfx9005
server sas.ntp.gus.com iburst
server sas2.ntp.gus.com iburst
server sas1.ntp.gus.com iburst
dbfx9007
server sas.ntp.gus.com iburst
server sas2.ntp.gus.com iburst
dbfx9008
server sas.ntp.gus.com iburst
server sas2.ntp.gus.com iburst
server sas.ntp.gus.com iburst
```

### What i'm Looking to Do:

The `dbfx9005` and `dbfx9007` are the Server Name, and anything Starting with `server` are NTP servers.
I am looking forward a way to validate if every Server below it contains below three NTP servers.

```
sas.ntp.gus.com 
sas2.ntp.gus.com
sas1.ntp.gus.com
```

If any of them not these then Just report it like `sas2.ntp.gus.com` not in `dbfx9005` .

**Edit:**
I want `sas.ntp.gus.com , sas2.ntp.gus.com and sas1.ntp.gus.com` these three named to be there but in case either of them missing of repeating then just  print them only indicating a server name.

I am okay any idea with Shell or Python or Pandas.

Thank you all for helping in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilising GNU awk:

```
awk '!/ntp/ {srv=$0;next } /sas((1)|(2))?.ntp.[[:alnum:]]+.[[:alnum:]]+/ { map[srv][$2]="1" } END { for (i in map) { if (map[i]["sas.ntp.gus.com"]!="") { print i" - sas.ntp.gus.com exists" } else { print i" - sas.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist" }; if (map[i]["sas1.ntp.gus.com"]!="") { print i" - sas1.ntp.gus.com exists" } else { print i" - sas1.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist" };if (map[i]["sas2.ntp.gus.com"]!="") { print i" - sas2.ntp.gus.com exists" } else { print i" - sas2.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist" }; }}' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk '!/ntp/ {
              srv=$0;                                                  # For lines not containing "ntp" track the server name in the variable srv
              next 
            } 
      /sas((1)|(2))?.ntp.[[:alnum:]]+.[[:alnum:]]+/ { 
              map[srv][$2]="1"                                          # For ntp lines, use a 2 dimensional array with srv the first index and the ntp server address the second index
             } 
         END { 
              for (i in map) {                                         # At the end of processing the file, loop through the servers in the array map
                if (map[i]["sas.ntp.gus.com"]!="") { 
                   print i" - sas.ntp.gus.com exists"                  # If a second index exists for "sas.ntp.gus.com", print that it exists, otherwise print that it doesn't
                } 
                else { 
                   print i" - sas.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist" 
                }; 
                if (map[i]["sas1.ntp.gus.com"]!="") { 
                   print i" - sas1.ntp.gus.com exists"                  # Follow the same logic for sas1 that was followed for sas
                } 
                else { 
                   print i" - sas1.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist" 
                };
                if (map[i]["sas2.ntp.gus.com"]!="") { 
                   print i" - sas2.ntp.gus.com exists"                   # Follow the same logic for sas2 that was used for sas
                } 
                else { 
                   print i" - sas2.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist" 
                }; 
               }
              }' file
```

Output:

```
dbfx9005 - sas.ntp.gus.com exists
dbfx9005 - sas1.ntp.gus.com exists
dbfx9005 - sas2.ntp.gus.com exists
dbfx9007 - sas.ntp.gus.com exists
dbfx9007 - sas1.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist
dbfx9007 - sas2.ntp.gus.com exists
dbfx9008 - sas.ntp.gus.com exists
dbfx9008 - sas1.ntp.gus.com DOESNT exist
dbfx9008 - sas2.ntp.gus.com exists
```

Comment: Raman, thanks a lot for placing a nice idea, but how i could determine if any of the host having missing any of these three ntp entries of having diffrent name than these ones.

Comment: So you want to check for entries that have ntp but not ones with ntp but also sas, sas1 or sas2?

Comment: Raman, literally i want `sas.ntp.gus.com , sas2.ntp.gus.com and sas1.ntp.gus.com` these three named to be there but in case either of them missing of repeating then just  print them only indicating a server name. I have updated my post . Sorry for leading any confusion.

Comment: I've amended the answer utilising GNU awk as opposed to grep.

Comment: Thank you Raman so much, this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Sorry for returning again, `map[srv][$2]="1"` what does its signifies `[$2]="1"` , specially `1` here?

Comment: It is settig a two dimensional array value to 1 so that ut can later be checked in the END block of code.